# JW Player API and Adobe DTM Analytics

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics, jwplayer6

How to get functions in the jwplayer api to loop through multiple objects of an array? For instance:

```
myArray = 'video1', 'video2', 'video3';
//jwplayer api functions
jwplayer().getPosition() and jwplayer().getDuration()
//currently I achieve this by pass an object one at a time like so, 

jwplayer(video2).onPlay(function(event){
 _satellite.track("videostart");
                 var q =  $(".sliderkit-selected a").attr('title'),
                t = jwplayer(video2).getPosition(),
                u = jwplayer(video2).getDuration(),
                initialPos = "-_--_--_--_--_--_--_--_--_--_--_--_-2-_-" + t + '-_-' + u,
                mm = 'Video : ' + _satellite.getVar('Page ID'),
                attr = cmAttributes(_satellite.getVar('cmAttr'));
            cmCreateElementTag(q,mm,initialPos, attr);
 });
```

I had written a for loop originally and it would only return the correct video on the jwplayer.onPlay() function while passing the value of video 1 through for getPosition and getDuration for every which ever video is chosen.  the variables below t and u is a function of how to integrate coremtrics into adobe dtm so please ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through `myArray`:

```
myArray = ['video1', 'video2', 'video3'];

$.each(myArray, function(index, value) { 

    ...

});
```